# Giving a sense to the formal equation $\sin x=-\pi\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}n\left\{\frac{nx}{2\pi}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, reference-request, fractional-part

Does there exist a formula giving a sense to the formal equation
$$
\sin x=-\pi\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\left\{\frac{nx}{2\pi}\right\},
$$
where $\mu$ is the Möbius function, $\{\cdot\}$ stands for the fractional part of a real number?

<s>Namely, the series on the right hand side does not converge</s>, but can it be made convergent to $\sin x$ after applying some "natural" summation method?

Comment: Yes. The correct limit is:


$$\sin(z)=-\pi\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(k)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\ln\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\left\{\frac{n z}{2\pi}\right\}$$

Comment: @Alex Could you give more details please.

Comment: [Answer](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~ramare/Maths/MoebiusTalk-1.pdf).

Comment: @Lucian Many thanks for the link!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series on the right-hand side does converge! ([H. Davenport, *On some infinite series involving arithmetical functions*, Quart. J. Math.
Oxford Ser. 8 (1937), 8-13.](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/os-8/1/8.full.pdf))

Comment: I don't think the issue is accessible to everyone. Do you have a link that is accessible to everyone? thanks!

Comment: the answer contains the link :)